# Python - Error On adding rows in the dataframe : local variable 'finallog' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Code Snippet

```
s = int(input())
       # finallog.append(pd.Series([CurrentClock,timedelta(seconds=s,minutes=m),CurrentProgramCode,0,0],index=finallog.columns()), ignore_index=True)
       # finallog.loc[j]=[CurrentClock,timedelta(seconds=s,minutes=m),CurrentProgramCode,0,0]
       # j+=1
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
             'CurrentTime':[CurrentClock],
             'BookingNumber':[""],
             'Duration':[timedelta(seconds=s, minutes=m)],
             'BrandCode':[""], 
             'TapeCode':[CurrentProgramCode]})
finallog = pd.concat([finallog,df_2],axis=0)
print(finallog)
```

Error message as:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-6144a7142686> in <module>()

----> 1 startup()

<ipython-input-25-1490643b2ba7> in startup()

     17        # j+=1

     18 df_2=pd.DataFrame(data={'CurrentTime':[CurrentClock],'BookingNumber':[""],'Duration':[timedelta(seconds=s, minutes=m)],'BrandCode':[""],'TapeCode':[CurrentProgramCode]})

     19 **finallog=pd.concat([finallog,df_2],axis=0)**

     20 print(finallog)

     21 CurrentClock=CurrentClock+timedelta(seconds=s,minutes=m)

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'finallog' referenced before assignment
```

Pls, suggest any workaround to make this work. Also if one of the commented out methods are better to add pls suggest because when I tried all seemed to be giving some or the other errors and all run-time ones. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you declare `finallog` somewhere above your code, but in other scope, but assign to it in a "current" local scope (may be somewhere below, because i don't see any assignment in your code):

```
finallog = pd.concat([finallog, df_2],axis=0)
...
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'finallog' referenced before assignment
```

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) advices, try to use `global`. Simplified example:

```
x = 10

def p():
    print(x)
    x += 1

p()
Traceback:
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d40139f363ae> in <module>
----> 1 p()

<ipython-input-2-271014bcda23> in p()
      1 def p():
----> 2     print(x)
      3     x += 1
      4
```

With `global`:

```
x = 10

def p():
    global x
    print(x)
    x += 10

p()
Out: 
10
```